# CSS ribbon breaks in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, ribbon

I created a ribbon for a H1 title tag.
Everything seems to work fine in Chrome, Safari, and IE9, but for some reason it breaks in Firefox.

Here's a screenshot of how it looks in Firefox:

[image]

Here's my CSS for the H1 tag:

```
#home .content h1 {
text-align: left;
position: relative;
color: #fff;    
margin: 0 -25px 20px -30px;
padding: 5px 0; 
background: #939393;
text-indent: 30px;
font: 1.3em 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

#home .content h1:before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-color: transparent;
bottom: -10px;
border-width: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
border-right-color: #464646;
left: 0px;  
}
```

I've tried

```
overflow: hidden;
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

I've also tried

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
```

But that didn't seem to resolve anything either

I've messed around with some of the margins and padding as well, but nothing seems to make it change in FF.

Here's a link to the site (currently as a demo):
http://dev.boostmktg.com/oas

Any suggestions?

Comment: could you provide html as well please

Comment: @EricLemos Post edited to include URL to site. Thanks!

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: can you remove the `h1` from `.entry`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like text-indent is pushing your ribbon 'shadow' 30 pixels to the right.

I managed to get it working in firefox by removing text-indent and giving h1 left padding of 30px

final css looks like this:

```
#home .content h1 {
text-align: left;
position: relative;
color: #fff;    
margin: 0 -25px 20px -30px;
   /* add left padding of 30 pixels */ 
padding: 5px 0 5px 30px; 
background: #939393;
   /* no need for this text-indent: 30px; */
font: 1.3em 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

#home .content h1:before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
border-style: solid;
border-color: transparent;
bottom: -10px;
border-width: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
border-right-color: #464646;
left: 0px;  
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! That did the trick. Don't know why I had the text-indent in there in the first place, but thanks again!